# Find Start/Stop Indices Where Array Is True

Tags: python

If I have a list that contains `True` and `False` values, how can I find the start and stop indices of where there are blocks of `True` values?

`x = [True, False, False, True, True, True, False, True, False, False, False, True, True, False, True]`

The output that I am looking for is:

```
[[0,  0],
 [3,  5],
 [7,  7],
 [11, 12],
 [14, 14]
]
```

Here, the value in the first column is the start index and the value in the second column is the stop index.

One solution that I have is:

```
start = []
stop = []
if y[0]:
    start.append(0)
for i in range(len(y)):
    if y[i] and not y[i-1]:
        start.append(i)
    if i > 0 and (not y[i] and y[i-1]):
        stop.append(i-1)
if y[len(y)-1]:
    stop.append(len(y)-1)

print(list(map(list, zip(start, stop))))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Enumerate

`for i in range(len(y)):` is an antipattern.  If you want indices (`i`) and the values at those indices (`y[i]`) the Pythonic way is using `enumerate`:

```
for i, yi in enumerate(y):
```

## Start indices

Let's take a moment and split this task into two parts: the start indices and the stop indices.  First, the start indices:

```
start = []
if y[0]:
    start.append(0)
for i in range(len(y)):
    if y[i] and not y[i-1]:
        start.append(i)
```

That almost looks like it could be replaced by list comprehension ...

```
start = [i for i, yi in enumerate(y) if yi and not y[i-1]]
```

... except for that `y[i-1]` part, which may wrap around and grab a value from the end of the array.  What you really want to do is `zip` the `y[i]` and `y[i-1]` sequences together.  We just need to start the `y[i-1]` sequence off with a leading `False` value:

```
start = [i for i, (y1, y2) in enumerate(zip([False] + y[:-1], y)) if y2 > y1]
```

## Stop indices

The stop indices are similar, zipping `y[i]` with `y[i+1]` with a trailing `False`:

```
stop = [i for i, (y1, y2) in enumerate(zip(y, y[1:] + [False])) if y2 < y1]
```

## Groupby

And now for something completely different.

`itertools.groupby()` takes sequential items with matching keys, groups them together, and emits them together with their key.  We just need the `True` and `False` values to be the key, and attach the index numbers to the `True`/`False` values.

```
>>> [list(group) for key, group in groupby(enumerate(x), key=lambda ix: ix[1])]
[[(0, True)],
 [(1, False), (2, False)],
 [(3, True), (4, True), (5, True)],
 [(6, False)],
 [(7, True)],
 [(8, False), (9, False), (10, False)],
 [(11, True), (12, True)],
 [(13, False)],
 [(14, True)]]
```

(output reformatted to show one inner list per line, for clarity)

But we only want the groups where the `key` is `True`:

```
>>> [list(group)
...  for key, group in groupby(enumerate(x), key=lambda ix: ix[1])
...  if key]
[[(0, True)],
 [(3, True), (4, True), (5, True)],
 [(7, True)],
 [(11, True), (12, True)],
 [(14, True)]]
```

For each group, we want the first and the last items in the group:

```
>>> [[group[0], group[-1]]
...  for group in (list(group)
...                for key, group in groupby(enumerate(x),
...                                          key=lambda ix: ix[1])
...                if key)]
[[(0, True), (0, True)],
 [(3, True), (5, True)],
 [(7, True), (7, True)],
 [(11, True), (12, True)],
 [(14, True), (14, True)]]
```

Actually, we only want the indices stored in those items:

```
start_stop = [[group[0][0], group[-1][0]]
              for group in (list(group)
                            for key, group in groupby(enumerate(x),
                                                      key=lambda ix: ix[1])
                            if key)]
```

Which gives:

```
>>> start_stop
[[0, 0], [3, 5], [7, 7], [11, 12], [14, 14]]
```

---

In the comments, [Graipher](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/98493/graipher) suggests:

> Personally, I would make getting the groups a generator expression assigned to a variable and then iterator over that in a list comprehension ...

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

groups = (list(group) for key, group in groupby(enumerate(x), key=itemgetter(1))
                      if key)
start_stop = [[group[0][0], group[-1][0]] for group in groups]
```

> ... using `operator.itemgetter` (instead of the `lambda ix: ix[1]`) for some more readability.

---

In the comments, [RootTwo](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/98633/roottwo) suggests:

> This could be simplified by grouping the indices directly instead of using `enumerate`:

```
[(group[0], group[-1]) for group in (
 list(group) for key, group in groupby(range(len(x)), key=x.__getitem__) if key)]
```

---

Timings, for a list of 15,000,000 entries (the original `x` list, replicated one million times):

```
Original:   7.3 seconds
AJNeufeld:  6.4 seconds
Graipher:   5.5 seconds
RootTwo:    3.1 seconds
```

Comment: `itertools.groupby` is also what I would have recommended. Although the list comprehensions are really hard to grasp starting from the second to last. Personally, I would make getting the groups a generator expression assigned to a variable and then iterator over that in a list comprehension: `groups = (list(group) for key, group in groupby(enumerate(x), key=itemgetter(1)) if key); start_stop = [[group[0][0], group[-1][0]] for group in groups]`. And use `operator.itemgetter` for some more readability.

Comment: @Graipher I did make the groups a generator expression in the last & second last.  :-)   I left it as list comprehension for the first two, so if the OP tried them out in a REPL or printed them, they'd see an actual result instead of seeing `<generator_expression(#14)>`.

Comment: I know, I would pull it out of the list comprehension and assign it to a variable, though. That nestedness took me a minute to read.

Comment: This could be simplified by grouping the indices directly instead of using enumerate: `[(group[0], group[-1]) for group in (list(group) for key, group in groupby(range(len(x)), key=x.__getitem__) if key)`.